# how to redirect www url to non-www url with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I wanted to know how to redirect users from http://www.mysite.com to http://mysite.com using htaccess, I'm not familiar in how to manipulate this file in order to do this, can anyone help me accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This site](http://www.neohide.com/htaccess-mod-rewrite-for-www-domain-name-prefix) gives a complete answer:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301, L]
```

It was the first thing that appeared when I googled for it, so I assume you didn't even bother to look for an answer (naughty boy, tsk, tsk!).

Comment: I did, but only found the other way around (non-www to www) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just add this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This site should be helpful:
http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/redirect-www-and-no-www/

Answer (score -1):

something like this should do the trick

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^www\.(.*)$ $1 [NC]
```

you want to google for "htaccess rewrite" to find more info about it

Comment: RewriteRule doesn't look up the host. Also, if he'd want to google he didn't ask it here.

Comment: ah forgot about the host,
regarding google: the original poster didnt seem to know about rewrite, hence not knowing what to google for, hence posting here.
i was providing the info what the keywords were to find out more on the concept rather than just providing a few lines of code.